# QT QML Items both in C++ and QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qquickitem

My goal is to describe a qml item in a qml file and then use a corresponding C++ class to add to the visual representation of this item.

I know it is possible to describe a qml item and use it in qml file and the communicate with it from c++ through signal/slots.

I also know it is possible to describe a qml item in C++ using QQuickPaintedItem and use it in a qml file (making it available through the register mechanism). Are there other ways?

So, the actual question is it possible to combine both in one item?
So, I want to have a qml item *and* a c++ class painting the same area, e.g. I have specific OpenGL code in c++ and a usual Rectangle Frame with MouseArea defined in qml.

Comment: Create your own item in C++. C++ is compiling language, qml is interpreted (in runtime), so it is not possible to use qml definitions in compile-time.

Comment: With QQuickPaintedItem I am able to use C++ objects in qml. 
With object->findChild<QObject*>("myobject") I can use qml objects in C++.
The question is, whether there is an object which is like QQuickPaintedItem but also can have a qml visual representation. The qt.labs.templates seem interesting.

Comment: You can combine C++ and QML in a single element by putting your QQuickPaintedItem-derived element above your QML element. You can do that by adjusting the z property or just by ordering the elements accordingly in a single QML file.

Since QQuickPaintedItem has transparent background, you will see your drawing output from both C++ and QML.

Comment: Just add stuff to it in QML: `MyPaintedItem { Rectangle{} }` and save it into `MyPaintedItemWithRectangle.qml`. Then use the `MyPaintedItemWithRectangle` type.

Comment: @Velkan This doesn't help with the rendering in code.

Comment: @PsiX, I use that while deriving from the QQuickItem, and the rendering works.

Answer (score 0):

After the hint from Andrej I decided to realize my goal of having both the qml representation and a C++ rendering class by creating a wrapper class which derives from QQuickPaintedItem and by this overriding the paint method. With this I can render into the item in code. The item is used in my main qml file.

It is a wrapper class because it loads the qml file I want to show through a QQmlComponent which creates the QuickItem I want to show, too. I do this by setting the parent of the loaded/created item to my wrapper class.
So in my QuickPaintedItem class (best done in classbegin, when engine is already initialized):

`QQmlComponent component(engine,QUrl("qrc:/myqml.qml"));
 QObject* object =  component.create();
 QQuickItem* quickItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(object);
 quickItem->setParentItem(this);`

Then myqml.qml is rendered and my paint method, too. And I have a central place where I can use both.

After the comments from Velkan, another way is to put the loading of the component in a [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) qml item:

`Wrapper { Loader{ onQmlChanged: source = newQml } }`

where onQmlChanged would be a slot which consumes a signal:

`signal onQmlChanged(string newQml);`

I cannot say which way is better performance wise. Defining the structure in qml seems easier and cleaner. A difference to the code version, is that it loads the item at creation time of the Wrapper, so during the creation of the main.qml and before it is shown.

Comment: How it's different from `Wrapper { MyQml{} }`? `Wrapper` is a `QQuickPaintedItem`, it's a parent to the `MyQml` from the `myqml.qml` file.

Comment: I can load the qml during runtime. It's a requirement.

Comment: At runtime: `Wrapper { Loader{source:...} }`.

Comment: The source, the file name of the qml file is read at runtime, too.

Comment: All at runtime, and dynamic: `Wrapper { Loader{ onSomething: source = "myqml.qml" } }`

Comment: Hmm, so if I get the qml file from a remote source (e.g. downloaded it in my app), I can the set the source property of the Loader object in my Wrapper?

Like this:
(qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(wrapper->findChild<QObject*>("loaderId"))->setProperty("source","myqml.qml");

Comment: it's not related to the question, but yes. Check it by putting a `Timer` into QML (with `onTriggered: loader.source = "myqml.qml"`), and create that file while the application is running.

Comment: Updated answer with qml solution.